# Git: git pull --rebase goes into a "detached HEAD" state

Tags: git, github

I've been having an issue that I am really trying to understand in order to fix it, but I cannot find any useful information on the web. I have a *Github* repo from which I'm pulling some changes using the *rebase* strategy, so I can keep a tidier commit history. This is something I've already done in the past without any problem, but now whenever I try to pull from **dev** branch (the default one on *Github*) with `$ git pull`, `$ git pull origin dev`, `$ git pull --rebase` or `$ git pull --rebase origin dev` when I have any committed changes, *git* just goes into detached HEAD state with the last commit uploaded to the *Github* remote repo. This is the output:

```
$ git pull
Note: switching to 'c350456eb80718e02415a95a5660502ef2eab405'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:

  git switch -c <new-branch-name>

Or undo this operation with:

  git switch -

Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false

HEAD is now at c350456 [doc](readme) Añade configuración de plantilla commit
Atención nombre de rama incorrecto⚠ 
No se cumple con las normas de formato de ramas:
    - Incluye alguna de las etiquetas (feat,fix,hotfix,refactor,style,doc,test,release).
    - Separado por / escribe un título para la rama.

error: could not detach HEAD
```

NOTE: *The text that says: "Atención nombre de rama incorrecto..." is from a post checkout hook I have created in order to check branches name against a naming convention*

This is the output of git status:

```
$ git status
On branch dev
Your branch and 'origin/dev' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

This is my local *git* repo config:

```
$ git config --local -l core.repositoryformatversion=0

   core.filemode=true
   core.bare=false
   core.logallrefupdates=true
   remote.origin.url=git@github.com:osr-solar/crm-backend.git
   remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
   branch.dev.remote=origin
   branch.dev.merge=refs/heads/dev
   pull.rebase=true
   commit.template=commit_template
   user.name=angbongon
   user.email=angbongon@alum.us.es
```

I hope someone can give me some guidance. Thanks in advance.

EDIT (10/13/2020):

Well, I found out that the `post-checkout` hook makes the rebase process stop. This in turn leaves the pull operation on the detached HEAD state. So the thing now is how to avoid the hook execution when a `git pull --rebase` is being made. I guess there is an option like `--no-verify` but I would like to find a better, more automated solution.

EDIT (10/14/2020):

This is my `post-checkout` hook:

```
#!/bin/bash

BRANCH=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
BRANCH_REGEX="(feat|fix|hotfix|refactor|style|doc|test|release)\/[a-z0-9._-]+"
MAIN_BRANCHES="(master|dev)"

ERROR_MSG="$(tput bold)Atención nombre de rama incorrecto$(tput setaf 3)⚠ $(tput sgr0)
No se cumple con las normas de formato de ramas:
    - Incluye alguna de las etiquetas (feat,fix,hotfix,refactor,style,doc,test,release).
    - Separado por / escribe un título para la rama.
"
if [[ (! $BRANCH =~ $BRANCH_REGEX) && ($3 = 1) && (! $BRANCH =~ $MAIN_BRANCHES)]]; then
    echo "$ERROR_MSG"
    exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

The problem? When the branch doesn't match de regex it exits **with code 1**, this is the code for an operation that wasn't successful in *shell*. When the code is thrown it makes the `rebase` operation abort what will eventually lead to the detached HEAD state.

Comment: Can you add some output from running those commands?

Comment: "...whenever I try to pull from dev branch..."  What command(s) are you using, and what output are they showing?

Comment: Adding to zrrbite's comment : would you by any chance have active conflicts when rebasing ? Check the output of `git status`

Comment: @zrrbite done! Check it out on the edit

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger I have made some edits to the post, check them out. Thanks!

Comment: @LeGEC no conflicts that I know of. I would be difficult to have conflicts right now because I am the only one pushing changes to the repository. This is the output of git status: `$ git status On branch dev
Your branch and 'origin/dev' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

nothing to commit, working tree clean`

Comment: With `pull.rebase=true`, `git pull` in your case is equivalent to `git fetch origin dev && git rebase origin/dev`. During the rebase process, first it checks out `origin/dev`, which leads to detached HEAD, and then `post-checkout` is invoked. But I don't know why the rebase process is interrupted. As I've tested, the failure of `post-checkout` does not interrupt `git rebase`.

Comment: @ElpieKay I'll try disabling the `post checkout` hook and see if that solves it. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!

As I explained in the post's last edit the problem was with the `post-checkout` hook:

> The problem? When the branch doesn't match de regex it exits with code 1, this is the code for an operation that wasn't successful in shell. When the code is thrown it makes the rebase operation abort what will eventually lead to the detached HEAD state.

So the solution is as easy as changing the exit code when the branch that is being checked out doesn't match the branch naming convention. **This is exit code 0**. Leaving the hook script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

BRANCH=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
BRANCH_REGEX="(feat|fix|hotfix|refactor|style|doc|test|release)\/[a-z0-9._-]+"
MAIN_BRANCHES="(master|dev)"

ERROR_MSG="$(tput bold)Atención nombre de rama incorrecto$(tput setaf 3)⚠ $(tput sgr0)
No se cumple con las normas de formato de ramas:
    - Incluye alguna de las etiquetas (feat,fix,hotfix,refactor,style,doc,test,release).
    - Separado por / escribe un título para la rama.
"
if [[ (! $BRANCH =~ $BRANCH_REGEX) && ($3 = 1) && (! $BRANCH =~ $MAIN_BRANCHES)]]; then
    echo "$ERROR_MSG"
>>> exit 0 <<<<<<<<<<
fi
exit 0
```

I think that you could control weather you are making a **rebase pull** or just changing branches looking at the parameters `$1` and `$2`, that are *the ref of the previous HEAD and the ref of the new HEAD (which may or may not have changed)* respectively. Looking at @torek answer would give some hints on how to tackle this "workaround" but for the purpose of my hook (being a warning message) I find my solution just fits.

Thanks to all the ones commenting. Specially to @torek and @ElpieKay who gave some clues.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

You have a post-checkout hook that is causing `git rebase` to fail (or stop without finishing, anyway).  You need to fix that, or use `git rebase --continue` or `git rebase --abort` if rebase itself recorded the in-progress rebase.

(It's clearly a Git bug that a post-checkout hook causes this problem at all, but precisely what the bug is—i.e., what Git should be doing: whether it should be using the post-checkout hook at all—is still not settled on the Git mailing list.)

## Long (and mostly tangential as it turns out)

Start with this: the `git pull` command is meant to be a convenience.  It runs `git fetch`, which obtains *new* commits from some other Git repository.  Then it runs a second Git command, because just *obtaining* those new commits doesn't *do anything with* the new commits.  You have them, but none of them are in any of *your* branches.  Your Git repository has its own branch names, quite independent of all other Git repositories, even the one you cloned to make your Git repository, and `git fetch` did not touch any of *your* branches.

You get to choose which second command `git pull` will run.  The default is to run `git merge`.<sup>1</sup>  You can choose to have `git pull` run `git rebase` instead.  How do you know which one to use?  That's up to you,<sup>2</sup> but if you choose `git rebase`, you now know that you need to know what `git rebase` will do.

---

<sup>1</sup>There is a rare case where `git pull` just runs `git checkout`, but in this rare case it doesn't matter which second command you chose.

<sup>2</sup>Often, my answer is *I don't know which one, if either, to use* and therefore I tend not to use `git pull` at all.  I like to run `git fetch`, *see what I got*, and only *then* decide whether to run a second Git command at all, and if so, which one to use.  But everyone has a different way of working; Git is a tool-set, not a solution.

---

#### When `git rebase` fails

When the `git rebase` works, all is good.  But when `git rebase` *fails*, you are left in this "detached HEAD" mode.

The word *fails* might be too strong here.  Rebase, in Git, is the equivalent of doing a series of `git cherry-pick` operations, one for each commit that rebase copies, and—just like `git merge`—a cherry-pick can have a *merge conflict*.  So each of these copies can result in a merge conflict, just like if you have `git pull` run `git merge`, or if you run `git merge` yourself.

What you have to do in this situation is resolve the conflict, then resume the operation (merge or rebase or cherry-pick—whatever it was that stopped).  That still doesn't explain the detached-HEAD though.  What *does* explain the detached HEAD is how rebase itself works.

## How rebase works, in a nutshell

Git is all about *commits*.  It's not about branches, though *branch names* help you (and Git) *find* commits, and it's not about files, though commits *contain* files.  It's all about the commits.

Each commit has a snapshot of all the files that Git knew about, at the time you (or whoever) made the commit.  Each commit has a hash ID: that's how Git actually finds the commits.  The branch name, if there is one, is just there to find the hash ID; the hash ID finds the commit.  And, each commit stores the hash ID of some *previous* commit.<sup>3</sup>  In our normal cases, that's the hash ID of *the* previous commit, which is how Git stores history: as a series of commits, linked up to each other, but *backwards*.

This trick where each commit stores the hash ID of its *parent* commit means that we can draw the commits like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here `H` stands in for the actual hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain.  Commit `H` holds a snapshot, and also holds the hash ID of its parent commit `G`.  That lets Git find commit `G`.  Commit `G` holds a snapshot, and the hash ID of its parent `F`.  That lets Git find `F`.  Commit `F` holds ... well, you should get the idea by this point.

We still have to know the hash ID of the *last* commit, though.  Would you like to memorize the big ugly hash ID of commit `H`?  I wouldn't.  But we can just have the *computer* remember it for us, using a *branch name*:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- branch
```

The *name* `branch` now remembers the hash ID of `H` for us.

When you have multiple branch names, each branch na

---

<sup>3</sup>Technically, each commit stores a *list of hash IDs*.  This list can be completely empty, or can be more than one hash ID, but the most common case is a one-entry list.  That's a normal everyday commit.  A two-entry list is a merge commit.  A three-or-more-entry list is also a merge commit, but it's mainly for showing off.  You don't normally find these in most repositories, except for with `git stash`, which makes weird merge commits that aren't regular merge commits.  And the very first commit anyone makes in a new, empty repository has that empty list: it's the *root commit*.

---

#### When you have more than one name, there may be more than one "last commit"

Look at what happens if you have two names.  They could point to the *same* commit:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- branch1, branch2
```

In this situation, it doesn't matter which name we pick: we'll get commit `H` either way.  We still have to pick one, though.  The one we pick, that's where we'll *attach* the special name `HEAD`.  Git will now know that that name is the name to use:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- branch1 (HEAD), branch2
```

This is the normal *attached HEAD* situation.

In this situation, when we make a *new* commit, we get a new commit whose parent in the current commit:

```
             I
            /
...--F--G--H
```

What Git does right after it makes this new commit, though, is to write the hash ID *of* the new commit—it's a new unique hash ID—into the *current branch name*.  So `branch2` still points to `H`, but now `branch1` points to `I`:

```
             I   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- branch2
```

Note that `HEAD` is still attached to the name `branch1`.

If we now `git checkout branch2`, Git switches back to commit `H`.  The files we saved in commit `I` are all safe there in commit `I`; but now we have the files that were saved earlier in commit `H`, and our `HEAD` is attached to the name `branch2`:

```
             I   <-- branch1
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- branch2 (HEAD)
```

Let's make a new commit now, and call it `J`, to get this:

```
             I   <-- branch1
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             J   <-- branch2 (HEAD)
```

Now let's go back to `branch1` so that we're working with commit `I`:

```
             I   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             J   <-- branch2
```

Note that no part of any commit has ever changed, in all of this.  The existing commits don't change at all.  We have Git copy the files *out* of the commit, so that we can see them and work on them.  We make *new* commits.  But none of the existing commits change.  They literally *can't* change.

#### "Moving" a commit

But what if we decide that it would be nice if commit `I` came *after* commit `J`?  We'd like commit `I` to change.  It *can't*, but we'd like it to.

So, instead of changing `I`, let's *copy* `I` to a new and improved commit, that's like `I`, but comes after `J`.  To do this, we'll use `git cherry-pick`, which copies one commit.  We'll start with `git checkout branch2` to get back on `branch2`.  Then we'll create a new branch name, `temp` for temporary:

```
             I   <-- branch1
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             J   <-- branch2, temp (HEAD)
```

Now we run `git cherry-pick`.  It needs the hash ID of commit `I`, for which we can find the hash ID, or just use the branch name—Git will find the commit hash ID *from* the name.  Either way, `git cherry-pick` does its magic, which involves using Git's merge code, and makes a copy of commit `I`.  Let's call the new commit `I'`.

Like any new commit, writing `I'` involves updating the *branch name*.  The branch name that gets updated is our temporary name, `temp`, because that's where `HEAD` is attached.  Here it is:

```
             I   <-- branch1
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             J   <-- branch2
              \
               I'  <-- temp (HEAD)
```

Now, we've already seen that while *commits* can't change, *branch name* can and do move all the time.  So let's yank the name `branch1` off commit `I` and make it point to `I'`:

```
             I   ???
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             J   <-- branch2
              \
               I'  <-- branch1, temp (HEAD)
```

Now let's attach `HEAD` to the name `branch1`, using `git checkout branch1` or similar, and then *delete the temporary name entirely:*

```
             I   ???
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             J   <-- branch2
              \
               I'  <-- branch1 (HEAD)
```

What happened to commit `I`?  Nothing: it's still in there.  You just can't *see* it any more.  Commit `I'` is the one at the end of `branch1` now.

It looks like we changed `I`, but we didn't.  We *copied* it.

#### Rebase is this, automated

This same process works even if there are multiple commits:

```
          A--B--C   <-- feature (HEAD)
         /
...--o--*--o--o   <-- main
```

can become:

```
          A--B--C   ???
         /
...--o--*--o--o   <-- main
               \
                A'-B'-C'  <-- feature (HEAD)
```

We just do a `git checkout feature` followed by a `git rebase main`.  The *rebase* command automatically:

- checks out the target commit, in this case, the tip of `main`;
- copies the commits that need copying, one at a time, using or as if by using `git cherry-pick`; and then
- moves the branch name at the end of the copying.

#### Rebase internally uses "detached HEAD" mode

When we did our manual one-commit-copy process, we made a temporary branch name, `temp`.  We did a `git checkout temp` to attach `HEAD` there.  Rebase doesn't bother with a temporary branch name, though.

Git has this *detached HEAD* mode in which `HEAD` just points *directly to some commit*.  This looks like this:

```
          A--B--C   <-- feature
         /
...--o--*--o--o   <-- main
               \
                A'  <-- HEAD
```

Here, we've successfully copied `A` to `A'`.  Then we stopped, for some reason.

The `git cherry-pick` command can stop in the middle for some reason: because of a *merge conflict*.  A merge conflict can happen with any merge, including the internal weird merge for a cherry-pick.  Since `git rebase` *uses* `git cherry-pick`, rebase can also stop in the middle.

If it does stop, your job is to fix the conflict and run `git rebase --continue`.  Or, if you decide the rebase is a bad idea, you can run `git rebase --abort`; then Git will give up on the rebase and just go back to an attached `HEAD`, abandoning any effort so far.  In this case that would produce:

```
          A--B--C   <-- feature (HEAD)
         /
...--o--*--o--o   <-- main
               \
                A'  ???
```

and it would look like you never started the rebase.

#### Since `git pull` runs `git rebase` ...

Since `git pull` actually *runs* `git rebase`, it can stop just like this, with an in-progress rebase that has suspended in the middle of a commit copy.  Your job is to finish the merge and resume the rebase.

Comment: Thanks for all that quality info. But I think you are not actually answering the question I made. I would like to know why a simple git pull --rebase, in which I am downloading the changes made remotely to a file I haven't edited locally. Normally this wouldn't cause any problem but it does now. Even if there was a problem git would enter to an interactive rebase mode in which I could made changes to the conflicting files, but it's not the case . After disabling the `post-checkout` hook I have been able to rebase without problem.

Comment: Aha - your post-checkout hook is causing the rebase to fail. It's still a case of rebase failing, it's just that it's because of the post-checkout hook. There is some discussion on the Git mailing list about this: in particular, whether `git rebase` should even *run* that post-checkout hook at all.

Comment: I think I can get away with it changing a bit of the code in the `post-checkout`. I'll update the original post so you can see the before and after of the hook.